# Why use a pre-processor directive for a 'case' statement?

Tags: c++

I was browsing through the SpiderMonkey engine source and saw some code in the interpreter that intrigued me.

```
// Portable switch-based dispatch.
# define INTERPRETER_LOOP()       the_switch: switch (switchOp)
# define CASE(OP)                 case OP:
# define DEFAULT()                default:
```

(source: *https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-b2g44_v2_5/source/js/src/vm/Interpreter.cpp#1579*)

Is there any non-stylistic benefit for defining something like `case OP:` as `CASE(OP)`?

Comment: if you really wanna know the details of why they are using this, portability over speed, you might want to read this publication
https://www.cs.tcd.ie/publications/tech-reports/reports.07/TCD-CS-2007-49.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Look up](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-b2g44_v2_5/source/js/src/vm/Interpreter.cpp#1553) half a screen:

```
#if (defined(__GNUC__) ||                                                         \
     (__IBMC__ >= 700 && defined __IBM_COMPUTED_GOTO) ||                      \
     __SUNPRO_C >= 0x570)
// Non-standard but faster indirect-goto-based dispatch.
# define INTERPRETER_LOOP()
# define CASE(OP)                 label_##OP:
// ... <snip>
#else
// Portable switch-based dispatch.
# define INTERPRETER_LOOP()       the_switch: switch (switchOp)
# define CASE(OP)                 case OP:
// ... <snip>
#endif
```

GCC and some other compilers support ["computed goto"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html), which is [faster than a loop-switch for an interpreter loop](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/07/12/computed-goto-for-efficient-dispatch-tables), but is non-standard and hence non-portable.

If the compiler supports computed goto, the first branch of this `#if` defines `INTERPRETER_LOOP`, `CASE(OP)` etc. to use computed goto; otherwise, the `#else` branch defines them in terms of standard facilities.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't catch the alternate definitions, it makes sense now.

Comment: But aren't switch cases already optimized to computed goto by the compiler if possible? Why is this needed?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc good question; Eli Bendersky discusses this in the article linked above. Firstly, a computed goto can omit a bounds check, but a further difference is that a switch jumps *from* a single location, while a computed goto jumps from various locations, so the branch predictor can "learn" the behavior of the opcodes; e.g. if a conditional jump is usually followed by a return.

Answer (score 7):

If you look higher up in the same source, there are different definitions for those same macros for different compiler syntaxes:

```
/*
 * Define macros for an interpreter loop. Opcode dispatch may be either by a
 * switch statement or by indirect goto (aka a threaded interpreter), depending
 * on compiler support.
 *
 * Threaded interpretation appears to be well-supported by GCC 3 and higher.
 * IBM's C compiler when run with the right options (e.g., -qlanglvl=extended)
 * also supports threading. Ditto the SunPro C compiler.
 */
#if (defined(__GNUC__) ||                                                         \
     (__IBMC__ >= 700 && defined __IBM_COMPUTED_GOTO) ||                      \
     __SUNPRO_C >= 0x570)
// Non-standard but faster indirect-goto-based dispatch.
# define INTERPRETER_LOOP()
# define CASE(OP)                 label_##OP:
# define DEFAULT()                label_default:
# define DISPATCH_TO(OP)          goto* addresses[(OP)]

//...

#else
// Portable switch-based dispatch.
# define INTERPRETER_LOOP()       the_switch: switch (switchOp)
# define CASE(OP)                 case OP:
# define DEFAULT()                default:
# define DISPATCH_TO(OP)                                                      \
    JS_BEGIN_MACRO                                                            \
        switchOp = (OP);                                                      \
        goto the_switch;                                                      \
    JS_END_MACRO

// ...

#endif
```

If you look further down in the same source, you will see these macros actually being used:

```
INTERPRETER_LOOP() {

CASE(EnableInterruptsPseudoOpcode)
{
    //...
    DISPATCH_TO(op);
}

* Various 1-byte no-ops. */
CASE(JSOP_NOP)
CASE(JSOP_UNUSED14)
CASE(JSOP_BACKPATCH)
//...
{
    //...
    ADVANCE_AND_DISPATCH(1);
}

CASE(JSOP_LOOPHEAD)
END_CASE(JSOP_LOOPHEAD)

//...

DEFAULT()
{
    //...
    goto error;
}

} /* interpreter loop */
```

Depending on the compiler, that code would compile to either this:

```
static const void* const addresses[EnableInterruptsPseudoOpcode + 1] = {
    ...
};

...

{

label_EnableInterruptsPseudoOpcode:
{
    //...
    goto* addresses[op];
}

* Various 1-byte no-ops. */
label_JSOP_NOP:
label_JSOP_UNUSED14:
label_JSOP_BACKPATCH:
//...
{
    //...
    REGS.pc += 1;
    SANITY_CHECKS();
    goto* addresses[*REGS.pc | activation.opMask()];
}

label_JSOP_LOOPHEAD:
    goto* addresses[JSOP_LOOPHEAD_LENGTH];

//...

label_default:
{
    //...
    goto error;
}

} /* interpreter loop */
```

Or to this:

```
jsbytecode switchOp;

...

the_switch:
switch (switchOp) {

case EnableInterruptsPseudoOpcode:
{
    //...
    switchOp = op;
    goto the_switch;
}

* Various 1-byte no-ops. */
case JSOP_NOP:
case JSOP_UNUSED14:
case JSOP_BACKPATCH:
//...
{
    //...
    REGS.pc += 1;
    SANITY_CHECKS();
    switchOp = *REGS.pc | activation.opMask;
    goto the_switch;
}

case JSOP_LOOPHEAD:
    REGS.pc += JSOP_LOOPHEAD_LENGTH;
    SANITY_CHECKS();
    switchOp = *REGS.pc | activation.opMask();
    goto the_switch;  

//...

default:
{
    //...
    goto error;
}

} /* interpreter loop */
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.